# How to create 3D globe view with OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, 3d

I want to create 3D view. and I am using OpenLayers.

Is it Possible?

Comment: Globe and 3D are not synonymous terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Cesium](https://cesium.com/). It is being used in OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 4):

If you need it to run in web browser then I would suggest OpenWebGlobe

http://www.openwebglobe.org/

It is a lot easier to make it work in modern browsers than Worldwind.

Comment: This webpage is now defunct and sends you to random webpages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is any way of doing 3D in OpenLayers. You could integrate something like Google Earth web plugin with OpenLayers by providing the ability to switch between the two. Another alternative would be the [WorldWind SDK](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/) from NASA.

Comment: Was not possible in OL2, but is possible in OL3

Comment: @sfletche ...but how?